# Jquery Ajax asks to download JSON file instead of going into success block

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am trying to upload an excel file to database in MVC5, which happens successfully, it then should show the data that has been uploaded. I am doing both these actions in a single action method

```
public ActionResult UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
          //logic to upload and get uploaded data into a DataTable "dataLoadedTable"
          ..
          ..
          string JSONresult;
          JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataLoadedTable);
          return Json(JSONresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am then trying to get this data using jquery ajax as below -

```
$("#formId").on("submit", function () {
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: 'UploadExcel',
                    type:'POST',
                    datatype: 'application/json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

But upon running the code the page asks to download the data as a json file, instead of going into the success block. Initially, I thought it's because the data is large. Even this doesn't work -

```
success: function (response) {
  alert("hi");
},
```

My HTML -

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload Excel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CommonLayout.cshtml";
}


<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "UploadData", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <form id="myDataForm">
            <div>
                <h4>Upload Data</h4>
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="p-5">

                        <label>Upload File:</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="file" autofocus="autofocus" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02" />
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUploadData">Upload</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            $('#inputGroupFile02').on('change', function () {
                                //get the file name
                                //var fileName = $(this).val();
                                var fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();;
                                //replace the "Choose a file" label
                                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);

                            })
                        </script>

                        <!--Display Error Message-->
                        <div style="color:red;">@ViewBag.Message</div>


                        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewData["Upload Success"] as String))
                        {
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mt-3" role="alert">
                                @Html.ViewData["Upload Success"]
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        }


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
    <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ABC</th>
                <th>XYZ</th>
                ..
                ..
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the below code was the issue. Will need to investigate more as to why -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadExcel", "UploadData", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

I simply replaced it with a regular html form and then added below code to get post the file object in the javascript -

```
var $file = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile02'),
                $formData = new FormData();

            if ($file.files.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $file.files.length; i++) {
                    $formData.append('file-' + i, $file.files[i]);
                }
            }
```

and added the following inside the ajax call -

```
                data: $formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
```

At the controller, got the file object using

```
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                    {
                        var _file = Request.Files[file];
                    }
                }
```

I think there was probably some conflict with the **FormMethod.Post** and ajax post. I could be wrong. Feel free to correct this and add to what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the form being submitted. Call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to the `submit` handler:

```
$("#formId").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // your ajax here...
});
```

In addition, you don't appear to be sending any `data` in your AJAX request? I'm going to assume this was accidentally removed when you wrote out the question.

Also, just as an aside, don't use `alert()` for debugging. It blocks the browser and coerces data types, which is the last thing you need when data consistency. Use `console.log()` or `console.dir()` instead.

Comment: It's still asking to download it. Not going inside the success block at all.

Comment: Ok, so your AJAX isn't being sent. There's a few possible issues then. One is that you've got your jQuery code too early in the page so the DOM isn't ready yet. Put it in a document.ready handler to fix that. Alternatively, your `#formId` form doesn't have that id, or there are multiple elements sharing that same id`

Comment: Tried with document.ready and also changing the form Id but no luck.

Comment: Could you add the HTML to the question.

Comment: The id of the form is `#myDataForm`, not `#formId`